# Makefile to compile files that begin with a pattern

Tags: makefile, design-patterns

My `makefile` has this line:

`OBJS = Test.o Test1.o Test2.o Test3.o ...`

Is there a way to make this automatic by matching patterns?

Comment: Are you trying to generate this list from the numeric sequence `1,2,3,...`, or from the existing source files?

Comment: @Beta, the former, but adding `Test.o`. In short: all the files that start with `Test`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gmake` - you can use the shell command to ls the source files, then `patsubst` command to convert the list of source files to the list of object files.

```
SRC=$(shell ls *.cc)
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cc,%.o, $(SRC))

all:
     @echo $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that what you're asking for is what you really want, but here goes:

```
NUMS := 1 2 3 4 5

OBJS := Test.o $(patsubst %,Test%.o,$(NUMS))
```

(There is a way to generate a sequence like `1 2 3 4 5` without spelling it out, but it's really ugly and not worth the effort.)